# Returned const char* not print a good string (cpp)

Tags: c++, string

I have the next code:

```
const char* NameErrorException::what() const throw()
{
    std::string to_return = "NameError : name '" + _name + "' is not defined";
    return to_return.c_str();
}
```

It should return a well "const char*" type string.
In the printing I do like this:
catch (NameErrorException myExcep)
                {
                    std::cout << myExcep.what();
                    system("pause");
                }

But instead of printing the right string, its printing me:

> ■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■ε■j

Why isnt that prints the right string? (By the way. I think its about the returning. because if I trying to print the same thing in the exception like this:

```
const char* NameErrorException::what() const throw()
{
    std::string to_return = "NameError : name '" + _name + "' is not defined";
    std::cout << to_return.c_str();
    return to_return.c_str();
}
```

It works.

Comment: What has this with C? You should remove `C` TAG.

Comment: Because you return a pointer to memory that no longer exists after the function ends. The string object you have in the function will be destructed when it goes out of scope, it will no longer exist and the same goes for the memory where the string data was.

Comment: The duplicate identified was an adequate description of the problem, but it didn't help provide the OP with a possible fix. The question is well written, containing code and output documented, so is IMHO worth answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_return` has *automatic storage duration*.

It goes out of scope when the function returns, so the pointer returned by `c_str()` is *invalidated*.

Normally, you'd just return a `std::string` instead and trust *return value optimisation* to obviate a deep copy. But if you *must* return a `const char*` then make sure that the supporting `std::string` instance remains in scope. Perhaps make that a member variable of your exception class?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning pointer to content of local variable. That's bad.

As soon as your function end, all local variables are being destroyed. You cannot return any data referring to them.

Return `std::string` instead.

Comment: Although you identified the cause correctly, your solution would be a departure from the convention of returning a const char* for the exception description.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I was focused on the main problem.